# C++ implementing cast based on runtime types

Tags: c++, casting

I'm pretty new to c++ and I recently decided to write a little calculator for practice. I want the calculator to be able to operate on integers and floats (and later different datatypes, e.g. complex numbers) as well, but I've run into a problem when trying to decide how to cast. Suppose that the user wants to perform an operation on an integer and a float. I want the integer to be casted to float in this case (this is a relatively simple example, once I implement more types this will become more complex). 
I've tried using templates for the function signatures, but that doesn't really help me:

```
template <class T> T add(T a, T b);
//...

//Operation is an enum
//data is a structure comprised of a union and an enum to decide which union member is used
void execute_operation(Operation op, data operand0, data operand1) {
    switch (op) {
        case Addition:
            //is operand0 or operand1 float? cast both to float : keep them as integers
            //also, decide on the cast made which union member of result to use
            data result = add(operand0.value, operand1.value);
        break;
    }
}
```

The only solution I've come up so far would be to hardcode a kind of casting table, but I'm pretty sure that there must be a better solution. I have worked with ruby and some other languages in the past that have a more dynamic approach to types, so I'm probably not "thinking c++". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on all the casting you're planning on doing? [std::common_type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) might solve your problem

Comment: If you use `auto` instead of a specific type declaration, you'll automatically get the common type.

Comment: You can't do casting at run-time, with the exception of `dynamic_cast` all casting is done at compile-time. Maybe you might be interested in e.g. [Boost variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/variant.html), or why not simple structure with a type-specifier and a union?

Comment: I'm currently planning on doing casting int and float to some kind of bignum type (that is not yet implemented yet), and ints to floats (bignum ints to bignum floats). I haven't really thought beyond that at the moment, but there might be more types in the future.

Comment: I'm not looking for casting at runtime, I am looking for an elegant way to implement the casting at compile time (i.e. not a clumsy casting table)

Comment: I advise you come up with the problem first, _then_ find a solution for it.

Comment: There's no such thing as "runtime types". (Well, there sort of is, but this ain't it!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of casting you can take two different template parameters and let the compiler do the implicit cast for you.  Take this little example

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto Add(T lhs, U rhs) -> decltype(lhs + rhs)
{
    return lhs + rhs;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << typeid(Add(1, .5f)).name() << std::endl;
   std::cout << typeid(Add(1, .5)).name() << std::endl;
   std::cout << typeid(Add(1, 3)).name() << std::endl;
   std::cout << typeid(Add(1.0f, .5f)).name() << std::endl;
   std::cout << typeid(Add(1.0, .5f)).name() << std::endl;
}
```

It outputs

```
f
d
i
f
d
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6cd3d624cd9402c)</kbd>

As you can see when one of the types is greater than the other the compiler will 
convert it for you.

Comment: Would this also work for self implemented types (promoting an int to bigint, for example)?

Comment: @BenSteffan As long as an `int + Bigint` is defined or if `Bigint` has a non explicit constructor taking an `int` then it should.  see this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e46a4f9ff106221

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `boost::variant` or `boost::any` for better type safety and scalability. Use `boost::variant` if set of types is finite and known at compile-time and `boost::any` otherwise (for example if new types can be introduced by pluggable library).

In case of `boost::variant` you will be able to write templated methods for operations and boost will translate them into runtime function pointers for all possible combinations of types.

Check out more details at boost docs.

Comment: It's not in the question, but OP said in comments he's after a compile-time solution. Runtime type erasure doesn't fit the bill.